# My Xinput controller now has left and right trigger mapped to the same axis when it wasn't before I formatted? Windows 10

Tags: controllers, windows-10

So the problem is, I'm using an Xinput compatible controller; Logitech F310. I formatted my PC recently **but** I was already running Windows 10. I just did a fresh re-install and now, my controller's Left Trigger (LT) and Right Trigger (RT) are detected as one axis. In other words, I can't use them together anymore. Prior to doing the re-install it worked as separate from each other so I can press both at the same time. How do I make it function like that again? Do I need to download a different driver or something?

While doing some more searches, I found [this thread](https://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=264&t=32002) that talks about how Windows 10 supposedly now supports separate axis for left and right trigger. So somehow, I got the old driver installed for me? How do I force it to use the latest.

In other words, this is what I should be seeing on the controller's property:

[image]

However, **this** is what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running Windows Update? Sometimes, Windows Update will automatically download driver updates. At least it does so for graphics and network drivers.

Comment: Yup, I'm on the latest available for the stable releases.